# Creating a mySQL sub query to list distinct rows from two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries:

```
'SELECT * FROM `table `WHERE weight = 0 OR weight IS NULL'
```

and

```
'SELECT * FROM `table `
```

The first query returns around 4000 values, the second query returns around 4100.

I'm attempting to create a query that will return the rows which are distinct between the two values, I'm attempting this by using a nested or sub query but I'm struggling with syntax here. Having only worked with very simple queries before. Could anyone suggest how I might do this.

Comment: Use a single query with `WHERE weight <> 0 AND weight IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE NOT (weight = 0 OR weight IS NULL);
```

That is more simply written as:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE weight <> 0;
```

Comment: Fantastic, I overlooked the NOT operator embarrassingly

Answer (score 1):

use MINUS operator as below

```
 SELECT * FROM `table`
 MINUS
 SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE weight = 0 OR weight IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE (table1.weight = 0 OR table1.weight IS NULL)
AND table1.Column not in (SELECT table2.column
                          FROM table2)
```